# Converting a dataframe to dataset retains extra columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

In `Spark 2.11`, when converting a Dataframe to a Dataset, spark retains the extra columns that are not even referred in the class of the dataset.

```
scala> case class F(x: String, y: String)
defined class F

scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> val df = Seq(("1a","2a","3a","4a"), ("5a", "6a", "7a","8a")).toDF("w","x","y","z")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [w: string, x: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val ds = df.to
toDF   toJSON   toJavaRDD   toLocalIterator   toString

scala> val ds = df.as
as   asInstanceOf

scala> val ds = df.as[F]
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[F] = [w: string, x: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> ds.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  w|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+
| 1a| 2a| 3a| 4a|
| 5a| 6a| 7a| 8a|
+---+---+---+---+
```

This throws the type safety aspect of it down the drain. Is there a way to prevent this from happening ?

I read that using `ds.map(identity)` because the conversion is supposed to be lazy but it does not trigger when trying to write the dataframe. Plus it's impossible to write a test to cover `.map(identity)` and prevent deletion.

Answer (score 3):

You can address this behavior in several ways but one of the easiest and most performant option in scala in to define your own `to[T]` method that selects only the appropriate columns:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object SparkExtensions {
  implicit class ExtendedDataFrame(df: DataFrame) {
    def to[T <: Product: TypeTag]: Dataset[T] = {
      import df.sparkSession.implicits._
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
      df.select(Encoders.product[T].schema.map(f => col(f.name)): _*).as[T]
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can than use in the following way:

```
scala> case class F(x: String, y: String)
defined class F

scala> import SparkExtensions._
import SparkExtensions._

scala> val df = Seq(("1a","2a","3a","4a"), ("5a", "6a", "7a","8a")).toDF("w","x","y","z")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [w: string, x: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val ds: Dataset[F] = df.to[F]
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[F] = [w: string, x: string]

scala> ds.show()
+---+---+
|  w|  x|
+---+---+
| 1a| 2a|
| 5a| 6a|
+---+---+
```

If you don't want to define an implicit class, you can always simply do `df.as[F].rdd.toDS` to achieve the same result in a slightly less runtime efficient way.

Comment: I would prefer not to add implicit but the second way is almost impossible to justify as a test since it does not change anything. The code can be removed without any guard and the bug swoops back in

Comment: I went ahead with explicitly removing the columns not required and adding a test which writes the file and reads it to confirm the content.

Comment: You can write a test with either method by comparing the columns of your result dataset with the columns inferred by your product type,  i.e something like `assert ds.columns == Encoders.product[F].schema.map(_.name)`

Comment: The real reason why the above way to test fails is because when you perform an operation on the dataset obtained, say convert it to a list to verify the values to assert on it, the lazy evaluation gets done and the extra field gets dropped. But the exact same thing won't happen when you call `.write()` or `.show()`.  So your test will pass but your code won't run as required

Comment: Well you should  the test as described with a simple `as[T]` and `as[F].rdd.toDS` and see for yourself if they perform as expected. Spark builds its output schema during the analysis phase so don't actually need to write an output to assert the behavior